# Python sockets and UDP: how the packet queue helps with a sender that's faster than a receiver

Tags: python, sockets, udp

There's a receiver that loops and calls `socket.recv`:

```
import socket
import time

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # Internet  # UDP

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.settimeout(0.001)

while True:
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1024)  # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    except socket.timeout:
        pass

    time.sleep(0.01)
```

---

And a sender loops and sends messages with `socket.sendto`, counting upward:

```py
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # Internet  # UDP

TOTAL_TO_SEND = 10000

messages = [str.encode(f"{num}") for num in range(TOTAL_TO_SEND)]

for total_sent in messages:
    sock.sendto(total_sent, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

---

With this setup, the receiver is not looping fast enough to get back to the `recv` line by the time the sender has sent the next message.

With UDP allowing lost data, I thought perhaps the messages that arrived while the receiver hadn't gotten back to `recv` yet would simply be skipped. But that's not the case.

When I send only 10,000 messages (`TOTAL_TO_SEND = 10000`), even though the send finishes almost instantly, the receiver takes some time to get through all 10000 messages, but it doesn't skip any. This implies there is some buffer/queue for messages that arrived while the receiver wasn't ready, and they're being stored until the receiver code is able to handle them all.

But when I send 10x as many messages (`TOTAL_TO_SEND = 100000`), there is some cutoff (15355 for my latest run) below which every single message is handled, and after which it skips hundreds at a time. This implies to me that the buffer/queue became full, and the loop was then only fast enough to handle one message out of every couple hundred sent.

More evidence of the finite-size-queue theory is that increasing the message size (by prepending some 0's to each message) lowers the cutoff where messages start getting skipped. Prepending 100 0's to each message causes the cutoff to be at 641 instead of 15355.

I have not been able to find a thorough explanation of this behavior, so wondered if anyone here knew how this "packet queue" worked in Python sockets, and what its parameters are. Is its size known? Can it be increased? Is there a time limit before messages disappear? Is there documentation of this?

Thanks!

Comment: It has nothing to do with Python, the operating system has a packet buffer.

Comment: If you want details about configuring it, ask on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. The packet buffer you mention: do you know if setting it too high causes issues, and what ballpark "too high" is?

Comment: There are *two* buffers: a socket send buffer at the sender, and a socket receive buffer at the receiver. You can control the size of both.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a "thorough explanation", but some info:

You can view and set parameters for a socket in Python with [getsockopt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockopt) and [setsockopt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setsockopt).

The relevant parameter in this case is the size of the receive buffer, i.e. `socket.SO_RCVBUF`.

```
print(sock.getsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF))
```

showed me `65536`.

You can use

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 65536 * 100)
```

to make it 100 times larger than that. This has the effect that 100 times more data is stored in the buffer before messages start getting skipped.

Making it too large may be a bad idea, but I don't know, so I'll let someone else chime in on that.